# Bootstrap 3 + Modal + Multiple Remote

Tags: ajax, bootstrap

Создаю модальное "окно" в бутстрапе, причем контент в него должен подгружаться с внешнего адреса. У меня есть ссылки: href указывает на нужный контент, а через атрибуты data-toggle + data-target я указываю что контент надо подгрузить в модальное окно.

```
<a href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/51/show/" 
   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click me #1</a>
<a href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/79/show/"
   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click me #2</a>
```

Мои попытки приводят к тому, что первый раз загружается что надо, а все последующие клики просто активируют уже загруженный диалог без смены контента. Помогите пожалуйста заставить BS грузить то, что надо.

http://jsfiddle.net/artoodetoo/NUCgp/2393/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно добавить

`$("a[data-toggle='modal']").on('click', function () {
     $('#myModal').removeData('bs.modal');
});`

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает: http://jsfiddle.net/artoodetoo/1n3x4u5r/